# Checking registry value on .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I need to check the value of a registry key and if the value is 12, go to label "exit", if 11 go to label "exiSt". What am I doing wrong below?

```
@echo off

reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\2C58473D30CCBEE4B9AF1E04A90EA0C6\InstallProperties  /v DisplayVersion

for /f "tokens=2" %i in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\2C58473D30CCBEE4B9AF1E04A90EA0C6\InstallProperties /v DisplayVersion') do (if %i  == "12.5.2000.01063" goto exit if %i == "11.1.0.07015"  goto exiSt)

:exit

Echo exit

:exiSt

Echo continue script bellow
```

Comment: In the text you say "if the value is 12", but in your code sample you compare a value against `12.5.2000....`; so please clarify - what do you actually want to check?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to use double percent signs `%%` for loop variables in batch files. Note that this differs from directly using the `FOR` command in the shell: there, you just need a single percent sign `%`.
- The registry key's value is outputted in as the third field, not the second.
- If you want to do an `IF`-then-`ELSE` on a single line, you need to use parentheses around both blocks. But this can be avoided in this case.

To summarize:

```
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%i IN ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\2C58473D30CCBEE4B9AF1E04A90EA0C6\InstallProperties /v DisplayVersion') DO (
    IF "%%i"=="12.5.2000.01063" GOTO exit
    IF "%%i"=="11.1.0.07015" GOTO exiSt
)
```

Comment: @Francisco: That means neither of the two `IF`s did match. Note I don't have a chance to see what data your `reg query` call actually returns. Try doing `ECHO %%i` before the `IF`s and see what's coming in.

Answer (score 0):

@zb226 already pointed out several issues of your code in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33543631/5047996). However, there are even more:

- you need to tell the script to exit after each section; at the moment, when you jump into the `:exit` section, execution goes on to the `:exiSt` section as there is no `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` command at its end;
- you should not use `exit` as a label, because there is also an `exit` command; although such a label works, it could make the code more difficult to read;

---

Supposing you just want to distinguish between `11.#...` and `12.#...`, you could do the following:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%V in ('
    reg query ^
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\2C58473D30CCBEE4B9AF1E04A90EA0C6\InstallProperties ^
    /v DisplayVersion
') do (if "%%V" lss "12" (goto :exiSt) else (goto :exi_t))
exit /B

:exi_t
echo exit script
goto :EOF

:exiSt
echo continue script below
```

This uses string comparison; a string beginning with `11` is always considered less than `12`, so this works. However, this approach fails when `%%V` contains a string like `9.#...` or `100.#...`.

---

You can also do numerical comparisons like this (supposing the registry value begins with a number):

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%V in ('
    reg query ^
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products\2C58473D30CCBEE4B9AF1E04A90EA0C6\InstallProperties ^
    /v DisplayVersion
') do (set /A "VALUE=%%V")
if not defined VALUE exit /B
if %VALUE% equ 11 (goto :exiSt) else (goto :exi_t)

:exi_t
echo exit script
goto :EOF

:exiSt
echo continue script below
```

The `set /A` command defines a temporary variable `VALUE` and assigns the registry value to it as a number; the first non-numeric character and everything after is ignored, which is the `.` in our situation. Hence a string like `12.#...` is converted to the number `12`.

The comparison is done in a numeric manner as there are no `""` around the comparison expressions. This will therefore work even if the value was `9.#...` or `100.#...`.

The logic here simply checks whether the registry value starts with `11` and jumps to `:exiSt` in case or to `:exi_t` for every other value. Of course you may adapt that to your needs.